# PostgreSQL + how to clean pg_xlog log without damage the PostgreSQL service

Tags: postgresql, linux, postgresql-9.2

we are using postgresql for ambari DB , in our linux server - rhel 7.2

```
postgres -V postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.2.13
```

we noticed that `pg_xlog` folder consuming 198g , and its gives `/var` to get 100% size

so after google searching

we noticed about `postgresql.conf` that have the parameter - `wal_keep_segments`

according to documentation , `wal_keep_segments` Specifies the minimum number of past log file segments kept in the `pg_xlog` directory

my questions are:

1. is it safe to use this parameter - `wal_keep_segments` , and doing purging on `pg_xlog` folder
2. based on the size of the folder that is nearly to `200g` , what is the value that we need to set to `wal_keep_segments`

Comment: Assuming the WAL files are the default size of 16MB, wal_keep_segments would have to have been set to at least 12,800 to drive 200GB of use.  If it was no set that high, then it is not the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask whoever set `wal_keep_segments` why they did it. Typically it is done for `pg_rewind` or streaming replication.

It is no problem to reset the parameter to its default value 0. Then, when the next checkpoint runs, old WAL segments should be removed.

Never delete WAL segments manually.

Comment: so you are recommended to set wal_keep_segments=0 ?  , sorry that I asked this , but this is production server and its very critical server

Comment: about "Never delete WAL segments manually." yes we are understand , thank you , but since the disk is full then we need to use the parameter -  wal_keep_segments ,

Comment: Setting `wal_keep_segements = 0`  will keep PostgreSQL happy. But the may be consequences, for example a standby server that loses connection.

Comment: do you mean if we have a standby postgresql server? ( sorry for the Question )

Comment: Yes, that might be one reason for the setting.